# Facing Operation Time Out Error while verifying Jenkins Connection within VSTS

Tags: jenkins-plugins, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to run VSTS Build through Jenkins Job. Jenkins is installed on my Local Server.I am trying to run VSTS Build through Jenkins but while verifying Connection, getting Operation Time Out Error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the Jenkins can’t be accessible from internet, just can access it from intranet, but you can ignore it (just click OK to save it) if you are using private build agent and can access Jenkins from this build agent. (can’t use Hosted agent, because your Jenkins can’t be accessible from Hosted agent)

An article about setup a private build agent: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Comment: I am following the Steps mentioned in the above link. After downloading the Private Agent.zip . I am running the below PS Command.

PS C:\agent> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem ; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("$HOME\Downloads\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.119.1.zip", "$PWD")
I am getting Error

Comment: What's the operation system? Could you unzip the package directly?

Comment: My Poweshell Version was 2.0 in a Remote VM. When I tried the same cmd on my Local Machine having PS 5.0 Version, Its working fine. Now I am able to run the Agent on VSTS Agent Pool.